# Входная строка и мела неверный формат

Tags: winforms, vb.net

```
Private Sub txtq_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtt.TextChanged, txtq.TextChanged, txtI.TextChanged
    If txtI.Enabled = False Then

        Dim I As Double
        Dim q As Double = Convert.ToDouble(txtq.Text)
        Dim t As Double = Convert.ToDouble(txtt.Text)
        I = q / t
        txtI.Text = Convert.ToString(I)
    End If

    If txtq.Enabled = False Then
        Dim I As Double = Convert.ToDouble(txtI.Text)
        Dim q As Double
        Dim t As Double = Convert.ToDouble(txtt.Text)
        q = I * t
        txtq.Text = Convert.ToString(q)
    End If
End Sub
```

При обработке пер q выдает входная строка имела неверный формат

Comment: просто я сам по c#, а тут VB.Приведение не правильно мб?

Comment: запятая вместо точки или точка вместо запятой. формат дабл зависит от локали.

Comment: @КириллМякишев и в C# было бы совершенно так же.

Answer (score 0):

Используй `Double.TryPrase` и сообщай пользователю, что он ввёл ерунду.

Также обрати внимание на использование точки или запятой для дробной части. По умолчанию ввод в текущей локали, но в `Double.TryPrase` можно явно указать другую.

Answer (score 0):

Все ок!=)
Поменял Convert.ToDouble на Val